# Android Error At com.example.crud_listview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.crud_listview;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employee_database";
    MaterialButton mAddEmp, mViewEmp;
    EditText mTextName, mTextSalary;
    Spinner mSpinnerDepartment;

    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewEmp = findViewById(R.id.btnViewEmployees);
        mAddEmp = findViewById(R.id.btnAddEmployee);
        mTextName = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        mTextSalary = findViewById(R.id.editTextSalary);
        mSpinnerDepartment = findViewById(R.id.spinnerDepartment);

        mAddEmp.setOnClickListener(this);
        mViewEmp.setOnClickListener(this);

        mDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        mCreateEmployeeTable();
    }

    private void mCreateEmployeeTable() {
        mDatabase.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (\n" +
                        "    id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n" +
                        "    name varchar(200) NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    department varchar(200) NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    joiningdate datetime NOT NULL,\n" +
                        "    salary decimal(5,2) NOT NULL\n" +
                        ");"
        );
    }

    private boolean inputsAreCorrect(String name, String salary) {
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            mTextName.setError("Please enter a name");
            mTextName.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }

        if (salary.isEmpty() || Integer.parseInt(salary) <= 0) {
            mTextSalary.setError("Please enter salary");
            mTextSalary.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void addEmployee() {

        String eName = mTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String eSalary = mTextSalary.getText().toString().trim();
        String eDept = mSpinnerDepartment.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String eJoiningDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        if (inputsAreCorrect(eName, eSalary)) {

            String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO employees \n" +
                    "(name, department, joiningdate, salary)\n" +
                    "VALUES \n" +
                    "(?, ?, ?, ?);";

            mDatabase.execSQL(insertSQL, new String[]{eName, eDept, eJoiningDate, eSalary});

            Toast.makeText(this, "Employee Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAddEmployee:
                addEmployee();
                break;
            case R.id.btnViewEmployees:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, EmployeeActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:text="Add a new Employee"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:hint="Enter Employee Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Select Department" />


                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerDepartment"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/departments" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextSalary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:hint="Enter Employee Salary"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnAddEmployee"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Add Employee"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/color_green" />

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnViewEmployees"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="View Employees"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

2023-09-27 20:34:07.248 29141-29141/? E/e.crud_listvie: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x800000
2023-09-27 20:34:07.460 29141-29141/com.example.crud_listview E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2023-09-27 20:34:07.598 29141-29141/com.example.crud_listview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.crud_listview, PID: 29141
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crud_listview/com.example.crud_listview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.crud_listview:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.crud_listview:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8024)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.crud_listview:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.crud_listview:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.crud_listview:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1131)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1092)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
**at com.example.crud_listview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)**

Line number 30 is like **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)** in the ActivityMain.java

It creates the android app perfectly but when i try to open the app in my mobile, it crashes, i have checked the whole code but couldn't find any error

Comment: Sorry but Stackoverflow is not a code and log dump. Please write a question and only include relevant information (e.g. layouts are usually not relevant) and only relevant code parts. If there is an error mark the line where the error occurs as nobody wants to count which is line 30.